# Write text on last line of document

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed, awk

If I have this document

```
aaa  
bbb  
ccc
```

And I want to add " ddd" on the last line. My document should look like this:

```
aaa  
bbb  
ccc ddd
```

How can I do this? If I prefer awk or sed but i'm open to your proposals. Thanks

Comment: may by you should tell all the problem at once, you want to add a fixed string, a file, part of a file ? in last line ? add many lines ;; ?

Answer (score 2):

In this case `sed` is the simplest. To add text to the last line of file `f`:

```
sed '$s/$/ ddd/' f
```

To append contents of a file `ff` after the last line of file `f`, one of:

```
sed '$r ff' f

cat ff >> f
```

To append contents of a file `ff` (with only one line of data) to the last line of file `f`:

```
sed '$s/$/ '$(< ff)'/' f
```

Comment: And if I want to add content of a text file instead of ddd?

Comment: Answer extended to your new question (and more variants).

Comment: Actualy is not working. The last command display me what I want but I want to save the result in a file. Something like this 'cat sed '$s/$/ '$(<  ff)'/' f' >> fff

Comment: There's a spurious quote in your command; try `cat sed '$s/$/ '$(< ff)'/' f >> fff` instead.

Comment: Remove the `cat` from my previous comment (I copied it from your code without noticing).